# Cert Error when trying to share project in Github

Tags: pycharm

I have my projects and when I try to upload it to Gihub, won't work.
I'm using Pycharm IDE and getting Cert Error when trying to share the project in Github

Comment: Can you share the error? If you can't copy and paste it, use a screenshot.

Comment: Please find the screenshot of the error...  @KTibow

Comment: Successfully created project 'Multiple_ShowCommands_Send' on GitHub, but initial push failed: unable to access 'https://github.kohls.com/tkmamja/Multiple_ShowCommands_Send.git/': SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Comment: Wait... github.kohls.com? Kohls is a store. I think you meant to set the origin to github.com.